# LARAVEL - Ocupar más de una collección de datos en una vista

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con LARAVEL pero necesito ocupar dos colecciones de datos en una vista. Una retorna una consulta sin filtro y la otra es una consulta filtrada, ambas se ejecutan por procedimiento almacenado. La pregunta acá es... ¿Cómo puedo mandar ambas colecciones a la misma vista? ya que son métodos diferentes.

NOTA: El metodo "showHistorial()", muestra los registros relacionados a un registro mostrado en "index()"

Espero me haya podido explicar y me puedan ayudar al respecto, por su atención ¡gracias!

```
public function index()
    {

        $tickets = DB::select('call ticket(?,?)',array(2,0));
        /*El cero (segundo parametro), no significa nada*/

        return view('index',['tickets' => $tickets]);
    }

    public function showHistorial($idTicket)
    {
        $historiales = DB::select('call ticket(?,?)',array(3,$idTicket));

        return view::make('index')->with('historiales',$historiales);
    }
}
```

```
@extends('layouts/plantillaPadre')
@section('content')
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Tickets <i class='uil uil-post-stamp'></i></h1>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            @if(Session::has('message'))
                <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('class') }}">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
            @endif

            <!--Inicio de Busqueda Filtrada-->
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <h2>Busqueda por filtro</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-bottom:auto; margin-top:auto;">
                                <div class="tab-content" id="controlesConsult">
                                    <input type="date" />
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display:initial; width:130px;" placeholder="Servicios">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn" style="margin-left:-30px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display:initial; width:130px;" placeholder="Ticket">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn" style="margin-left:-30px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" style="display:initial; width:130px;" placeholder="Asunto">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn" style="margin-left:-30px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Final de Busqueda Filtrada-->
            <!--Inicio de Listado de Tickets-->
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <h2>Listado de Tickets</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div style="position:relative; margin-left:960px; top:10px;">
                                    <a href="#NuevoTicketModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Nuevo Ticket</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="tabbable-panel">
                                <div class="tabbable-line">
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <table class="table table-striped" id="example">
                                            @if(count($tickets) > 0)
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Ticket</strong></th>
                                                        <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Asunto</strong></th>
                                                        <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Clasificación</strong></th>
                                                        <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Servicio</strong></th>
                                                        <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Estado</strong></th>
                                                        <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Fecha registro</strong></th>
                                                        <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Agencia</strong></th>
                                                        <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Reportado por</strong></th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center"><a href="{{ url('historial',$ticket->idTicket) }}" data-mytitle="Hello"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ticketModalPrincipal">{{ $ticket->Ticket }}</a></td>
                                                        <td align="center">{{ $ticket->Asunto }}</td>
                                                        <td align="center">{{ $ticket->Clasificacion }}</td>
                                                        <td align="center">{{ $ticket->Servicio }}</td>
                                                        <td align="center">{{ $ticket->Estado }}</td>
                                                        <td align="center">{{ $ticket->FechaRegistro }}</td>
                                                        <td align="center">{{ $ticket->Agencia }}</td>
                                                        <td align="center">{{ $ticket->ReportadoPor }}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Fin de Listado de Tickets-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Inicio del modal - HISTORIAL TICKET-->
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="ticketModalPrincipal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3><strong>Historial de Ticket</strong></h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="TicketModalBody">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Nombre</strong></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Estado</strong></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Fecha de alta</strong></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Fecha de<br />modificación</strong></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Historial de<br />seguimiento</strong></td>
                        </thead>
                         @foreach($historiales as $historial)
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">{{ $historial->Nombre }}}</td>
                                <td align="center">{{ $historial->Estado }}</td>
                                <td align="center">{{ $historial->FechaAlta }}</td>
                                <td align="center">{{ $historial->FechaModificacion }}</td>
                            </tr>                            
                        </tbody>   
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Final del modal - HISTORIAL TICKET-->   
    <!--Inicio del modal - Destinatario TICKET-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="DestinatarioModalPrincipal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content" style="overflow:scroll;">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="DestinatarioModalBody">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Final del modal - Mensaje TICKET-->
</div>
<script>
    $("#ticketModalPrincipal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
        console.log('Modal abierto!');

        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var title = button.data('mytitle');

        var modal = $(this)

        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(title)
    });
</script>
@stop
```

Comment: ¿Que problema hay en que llames a ambas colecciones y las mandes a la vista?

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido al momento de iterarlo en el foreach, no me reconoce la variable $historiales

Comment: Veo mezcla de sintaxis de diferentes versiones de Laravel, ¿Por que no lo tienes asi `view('index', ['historiales' => $historiales])`?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que me marca como inexistente/indefinida, dicha variable... otra pregunta es... ¿Estare mandando el id del registro, de la manera correcta?

<td align="center"><a href="{{ url('historial',$ticket->idTicket) }}" data-mytitle="Hello"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ticketModalPrincipal">{{ $ticket->Ticket }}</a></td>

Comment: Cuando presiona el botón, esos datos los quieres mostrar en un modal? Y si esto esta bien `{{ url('historial',$ticket->idTicket) }}` ingresa al chat para aclarar lo que necesitas https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91390/laravel-ocupar-mas-de-una-colleccion-de-datos-en-una-vista

Comment: Si asi es, cuando se clickea en el botón, debe mostrar un modal con los datos relacionados a ese registro, por eso implemento el uso de dos colecciones de datos en una vista

Comment: @CesarRomero la plataforma no me permite entrar al chat, ya que soy nuevo por aqui :c jeje

Comment: Para lo que quieres hacer tendrás que valerte de `Ajax`, `axios` por ejemplo, ya que al pulsar el botón debes obtener los datos de un historial en especifico. O almacenar de alguna manera toda colección completa en el navegador.

Comment: @CesarRomero Y con ajax, mando la url? o cómo?

Comment: Al presionar clic, debes enviar a un evento para realizar la petición `AJAX`, para que al recibir la respuesta (la colección la retornas como `JSON` para que la manipules con `Javascript` puro o usando `Jquery`

Comment: @CesarRomero me podrias orientar al respecto? por favor

----
var mostrarHistorial = function(idTicket){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '{{url('historial',$ticket->idTicket)}}',
            data: {idTicket: idTicket},
            success: function(){
                console.log(idTicket)
            }
        })
    }
----
no sé si lo estoy haciendo bien